# How to write a node in iOS?

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a iPhone app that's able to publish some message on a ROS topic. I found one implemented with RabbitMQ from here : https://github.com/tomas789/iOSmsg_client. However, I would prefer everything happens locally through http and ports. How do I do that? Is there any good resource?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273997/how-to-write-a-node-in-ios?/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: [wesgood/RBManager](https://github.com/wesgood/RBManager) seems to have been upgraded. New repo: [wesgood/RBSManager](https://github.com/wesgood/RBSManager). From the readme:

> A Swift-native library for handling the WebSocket connection to a Robot Operating System (ROS) master running ROSBridge. Control your robots with a mobile phone.

---

Old answer:

> everything happens locally through http and ports

I'm not sure I follow here: what 'ports' are you referring to specifically?

In any case: I'm not an iPhone dev (so I'm not too aware of the limitations that you are faced with) but you could take a look at [rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite). It essentially provides a JSON interface into a ROS application that you can then communicate with using anything that can work with JSON (which is just about anything these days). There are various implementations of `rosbridge` clients, but probably not in languages that are interesting when developing on iOS, such as [Rosbridge .NET Client](https://github.com/follesoe/rosbridge_client_dot_net) and [h2r/java_rosbridge](https://github.com/h2r/java_rosbridge), and the 'minimal Python client' that is available as part of `rosbridge_library` in `rosbridge_suite` itself.

And there are some projects that implement a plain HTTP REST interface to a ROS application, such as [rostful](https://github.com/asmodehn/rostful).

All of the above will require a *bridge* node running in your ROS application, they do not implement a native ROS client library.

If you'd like to avoid the bridging approach, an alternative might be [rosnodejs](http://wiki.ros.org/rosnodejs), which is a Node JS based ROS client library that foregoes the JSON serialisation of `rosbridge`.

If you are not limited to ROS 1, you might be interested in [esteve/ros2_objc](https://github.com/esteve/ros2_objc) (Discourse announcement [here](https://discourse.ros.org/t/announcing-objective-c-on-macos-and-ios-for-ros2/946)), which is an Obj-C client library for ROS 2. Using ROS 2 is probably a good idea with mobile devices anyway, due to the fact that they typically use (lossy) wireless networks. Note that I don't know what the status is of `ros2_objc`, you'd have to ask Esteve.

---

There have been some efforts in the past to implement Obj-C native client libraries, such as [younata/rosobjc](https://github.com/younata/rosobjc) and a Obj-C rosbridge client [wesgood/RBManager](https://github.com/wesgood/RBManager). But afaik those projects are abandoned or no longer compatible.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1